# Is texture switching a good idea (OpenGL, 2D)?

Tags: opengl, texture-atlas, multitexturing

Let's say I have two atlases for character animation. One atlas represent idle and walk.
The other one represents striking.

I usually combine atlases into one file, however I thought about using multiple textures. It is technically possible to bind another texture based on some state, but what are downsides of this approach?

It seems to me, like rendering and animation defining logic will get more complicated. I will have to implement not only UV/uniforms switching, but also rebinding of a texture, some kind of relation between GL_TEXTURE**N** and the texture object itself.

Is this practice usually considered? What are upsides and downsides compared to atlasing?

Comment: It sounds like you understand the downsides in terms of the extra code complexity this adds. Assessing whether that code complexity is worth the advantages you get from using separate textures is up to you.

Comment: @DMGregory I wonder if there are any additional advantages or disadvantages of this approah compared to texture atlasing (e.g. performance, texture bleeding problem, etc.)

Comment: If you're only sampling from one image or the other in a given frame (because your character is either walking or striking, not both), then it's not adding draw call cost. The only cost is the code binding the texture, which you can profile to measure exactly. If the images aren't next to each other in the same texture then they can't bleed together. So these don't seem like things you need to wonder about — you can verify the answers yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, atlasing isn't that easy to implement either. You have to associate each animation frame with texture coordinates. If your sprites are not adjusted to viewport pixels, you can have problems with texture coordinates rounding, causing neighbouring frames "bleed" into current frame.

Texture atlases are usually considered faster than switching textures. You are also not guranteed to have a lot of slots for binding textures ([How many textures can I usually bind at once?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30043/how-many-textures-can-i-usually-bind-at-once)).

Third option is to use bindless textures (https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Bindless_Texture). The OpenGL wiki article I linked goes into them in great detail, but TL;DR is that you can bind a texture, get a handle for it and then pass it to your shader as a uniform sampler2D variable. Changing a uniform variable for every texture might be as expensive as binding a new texture; however, you can bind more textures (if you create an array of samplers), or even bind 2DTextureArrays (unfortunately it requires every texture to have the same resolution, but it allows indexing textures with a layout qualifier variable, i.e. use multiple textures atlases in a single object).

Comment: I think I will just stick to atlasing for now, since it is fast enough + easier to implement imo. But having a look at Bindless texture and array textures is something I'll definitely need in future. Thanks :)

Comment: _"texture coordinates rounding, causing neighbouring frames "bleed" into current frame"_ - thats quite an unusual artist and coding mistake and I would not call it a point against atlas usage.

Comment: @Kromster since I don't have an artist and have to use open game art it is quite a common problem :D